# Read the contents of the import Package

Tags: java

I am working on creating a computer controlled bots for a game using Java. I got a example bot program and I am understanding this currently.

I am not able to understand what does @JProp means in the code below. Can any one help me on this. Also, how do I view all the contents of the import files at the start of the program.

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import cz.cuni.amis.introspection.java.JProp;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.agent.impl.AgentId;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.agent.module.comm.PogamutJVMComm;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.agent.navigation.IPathExecutorState;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.communication.worldview.listener.annotation.EventListener;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base.utils.guice.AgentScoped;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base3d.worldview.object.ILocated;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.base3d.worldview.object.Location;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.unreal.communication.messages.UnrealId;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.module.utils.TabooSet;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.navigation.UT2004PathAutoFixer;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.navigation.stuckdetector.UT2004DistanceStuckDetector;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.navigation.stuckdetector.UT2004PositionStuckDetector;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.agent.navigation.stuckdetector.UT2004TimeStuckDetector;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.bot.impl.UT2004Bot;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.bot.impl.UT2004BotModuleController;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.bot.params.UT2004BotParameters;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.UT2004ItemType;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbcommands.Initialize;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.BotKilled;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.ConfigChange;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.FlagInfo;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.GameInfo;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.InitedMessage;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.Item;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.NavPoint;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.Player;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.PlayerKilled;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.communication.messages.gbinfomessages.Self;
import cz.cuni.amis.pogamut.ut2004.utils.UT2004BotRunner;
import cz.cuni.amis.utils.Heatup;
import cz.cuni.amis.utils.exception.PogamutException;
import cz.cuni.amis.utils.flag.FlagListener;

/**
 * Example of Simple Pogamut bot, that randomly walks around the map searching
 * for preys shooting at everything that is in its way.
 * 
 * @author Rudolf Kadlec aka ik
 * @author Jimmy
 */
@AgentScoped
public class CTFBot extends UT2004BotModuleController<UT2004Bot> {

    /** boolean switch to activate engage behavior */
    @JProp
    public boolean shouldEngage = true;

    /** boolean switch to activate pursue behavior */
```

Comment: It appears to be an [annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) from "cz.cuni.amis.introspection.java.JProp", I hope they provided some Javadocs.

Comment: The `@JProp` annotation allows you to control the variable from NetBeans GUI. See this tutorial http://pogamut.cuni.cz/pogamut_files/latest/doc/tutorials/ch04s04.html

Comment: You open the files. They exist somewhere. You should find the source code, usually it's packaged with the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this JProp annotation is used for introspection purposes (allowing the contents of the variable which is decorated to be easily inspected from within your IDE).

Quoting [this manual](http://pogamut.cuni.cz/pogamut_files/latest/doc/tutorials/ch04s04.html):

> Introspection is designed to ease the bot's parameterization. It is
>   often needed to adjust multiple behavior parameters at runtime and you
>   will probably end up creating your own GUI (graphical user interface)
>   for this purpose. In introspection, you just annotate desired
>   variables with @JProp annotation and they will be accessible via the
>   Netbeans GUI.
>
> Let's look how logging and introspection works in EmptyBot example.
>   First start the bot (F6), then have a look on it's source code. In the
>   initial section several variables annotated with the @JProp are
>   defined.

```
@JProp
public String stringProp = "Hello bot example";
@JProp
public boolean boolProp = true;
@JProp
public int intProp = 2;
@JProp
public double doubleProp = 1.0;
```

> Now expand bot's node under the UT server node (in Services tab), you
>   will see two new nodes - Logs and Introspection. After selecting the
>   Introspection node the annotated variables will be shown in the
>   Properties (Ctrl + Shift + 7) window. Note that the intProp variable
>   is being continuously updated. New values of variables can be also set
>   in this window.